# How to write Jquery plugin for Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, google-analytics

I would like to create a **custom plugin for tracking events** in my JavaScript Application **using Google Analytics Measurement Tool (GA MT)**, but I am a newbie and not sure how to write such plugin.

My idea about the plugin:

- it should have **defined all types of events** I am going to track (i.e. starting of an application, button clicked, 1st, 2nd, ... slide entered, etc)
- if I understand how GA MT works correctly, I will need to specify an **event hit for each custom event** ([see more](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#commonhits))

  - part of the hit parameters (url) is **shared** (such as version, client ID, tracking ID...)
  - the other part of the url is custom, so I will store the differences in various functions inside of the plugin
- these functions will be later called i.e. on button clicked, on goToNextSlide etc, which will send a hit to GA.

This is an example of my plugin:

```
(function( $ ) {

    var $_document = $(document);

    // Shared hit parameters
    var hit =   'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?';
        hit +=  'v=1'; // Version.
        hit +=  '&t=pageview'; // Pageview hit type.
        hit +=  '&tid=UA-XXXXXX-Y'; // Tracking ID / Property ID.
        hit +=  '&cid=555';   // Client ID.



    /* Application opened */
    function gacAppOpened() {
        console.log('gacAppOpened');
        hit += '&dp=%2Fslide-1';           // Page.
        httpGetRequest(hit);
    }

    /* Slide-2 entered */
    function gacSlide2() {
        console.log('gacSlide2');
        hit += '&dp=%2Fslide-2';           // Page.
        httpGetRequest(hit);
    }



    function httpGetRequest( theUrl )
    {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", theUrl, true);
        req.send(null);
    }

}( jQuery ));
```

This is how I load the plugin (gaCustom.js) and my common JS file (app.js)

```
<script src="js/gaCustom.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

When trying to reach to my function from inside app.js, I got error (not a function)

```
goToDefault: function() { // loads first page of my app, 
                          // a hit should be sent to GA about app started    
    ...

    gacAppOpened();

    ... // render template
},
```

So I am wrong somehow in defining the plugin and using it. I also tried few other attempts, but all of them failed.

**I would appreciate to hear whether my approach is good or wrong and what to improve as I am a newbie and would like to do this correctly.**

Comment: Can I ask why you're choosing to use Measurement Protocol instead of native analytics.js or even Google Tag Manager?  Both of which you will find much more reliable from a URL parameters PoV.

Comment: That's because I have a hybrid application that has only file:/// URI. It's a JS web app injected into a iOS mobile app. Native analytics.js didn't work for me. I have to go with MP.

Comment: ok, I was mainly interested to make sure you weren't doing all this work when it could've been acheived in an easier fashion.  unfortuantely I can't give you a great deal of help with the plugin, that is very much a jQuery question and I'm no expert.  I do think its something to do with incorrect scoping though.  Good luck!

Comment: @VeryCurious, still don't get why you can't use analytics.js . If you can use  JQuery and you can send requests to Google Analytics, there is no reasons, why not to use standard analytics.js code. You can use ga object in your JQuery callback functions. See reply in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378287/how-to-make-lightbox-transitions-count-as-analytics-for-image-clicks-in-lightbox  Just for example.

Comment: The reason why I believe I can't use analytics.js itself it due to the generated snippet, which is created upon URL, which I don't have. When I tried to use it, I didn't get any response on the page. On the other hand, creating hits using Measurement tool works well. Am I wrong? I could not find other way to make this work.

Comment: There seems to be a scoping issue ( gacAppOpened is created in the scope of the immediately invoked  function but is call in the scope of the goToDefault function). Plus this does not look like a jQuery plugin since your methods do not extend $.fn. You can use analytics.js (the domain set in the interface does not matter, but on the file protocol you need to set "storage" to "none" when you create a tracker and provide your own clientids, since without a FQDN Ga cannot set cookies to maintain the clientid).