# How to make lightbox transitions count as analytics for image clicks in lightbox

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am not even sure I am asking this question properly, but I could not find any resources online that would help me in this regard.

Since lightbox transitions don't really register as photo clicks for analytics, I am trying to figure out a way to link the transition between photos to click counts during lightbox viewing in addition to the click count on each thumbnail image.

I found this from a previous thread which adds an afterload function  but am not sure where to paste it in my wordpress editor and how to modify it to include lightbox transitions when clicking on the front/back arrows:

```
afterLoad: function() {
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Lightbox','Open',this.href, ,true]);
 },
```

taken from this site: https://moz.com/ugc/tracking-fancybox-clicks-in-google-analytics

Here is a direct link to the photo gallery page: http://cultmontreal.com/photos/151020-justintrudeau-cl/

Thanks.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you probably have a piece of JavaScript which attaches the light box functionality to images. I am not very familiar with Wordpress, but if you haven't intentionally done this it is probably somewhere in the plugin. If you can edit that you can do it there. Risk is that you lose it when you update the plugin. Better would be if you can define additional options/extend options with your afterload.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is: how do I register an event every time a photo transition takes place on the lightbox?

First thing to note is that your code snippet in your question is for Google Analytics Classic (ga.js) however your site runs Google Universal Analytics (analtyics.js) so you need to use the correct code (not what is in your question).

First of all decide on values for the event you want to track and compose the JS for Universal Analytics in the format:

```
ga('send', 'event', '[category]', '[action]', '[label]', [value]);
```

Then you need to bind to the scroll event which is a click on the left/right arrows.  Fortunately these arrows both have classes of 'fancybox-nav' so you could bind to both of those and then just fire the tracking.

Only other thing to consider is that the overlays are created dynamically, so we have to delegate an event to every 'fancybox-nav' element in the body which ensures dynamic elements are automatically bound too.

Your complete code using jQuery would therefore be (remember to replace the placeholder texts):

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.fancybox-nav', function(){ 
  ga('send', 'event', 'lightbox', 'lightboxClicks', 'lightboxPhotos', 100);
});
```

Wrap this all in a jQuery(document).ready() wrapper and throw it in to any JS file that is loaded on these pages - probably best to be a JS file loaded through your template rather than the plugin so that it doesn't get overwritten regularly.

You need to [read the google docs about event tracking to fully understand it](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

To double check that events are firing, you'll need to debug/monitor the GA calls.  [See my brief overview of these techniques here](http://dmpg.co.uk/debugging-google-analytics/).

Comment: Thank you Rik and dmpg_tom for your responses. I will attempt to bind the left/right arrows with the solution you provided dmpg_tom and provide my result here once its done. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried the code you provided, @dmpg_tom. Here is what I used: 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('.fancybox-nav').on('click', function(){
  ga('send', 'event', '[lightbox]', '[lightboxClicks]', '[lightboxPhotos]', [lightboxValue]);
});
});' I added it to a js called placeholder.js. My question is, is how I can check to see if it is actually functioning. The ad man for the site looks over the analytics through his Doubleclick account. I can check there to see if it shows up in his metrics under the new category I made called "lightbox"

Comment: Nadim, couple of things: 1. you can remove the square brackets in your values, that was just to indicate that these were placeholders. 2. the lightboxValue MUST be an integer. 3. To check its working, you need to look at the HTTP calls in network tab of developer tools in chrome (or similar in your chosen browser) and look for event calls to google-analytics.com/collect?  this type of debugging needs some explanation so take a look at my guide here: http://dmpg.co.uk/debugging-google-analytics/

Comment: Hi dmpg_tom. Here is the final code I used: $(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox-nav').on('click', function(){
  ga('send', 'event', 'lightbox', 'lightboxClicks', 'lightboxPhotos', 100);
});
}); I added the Google Analytics Debugger for Chrome and checked it again today. I found this result: 

Dimensions1 × 1File size35 BMIME typeimage/gifURLhttp://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j39&a=859702087&t=pageview&_…_u=AACAAEABI~&jid=&cid=1936343171.1444761480&tid=UA-33431440-1&z=100889102. Based on instructions, I am not sure if this is the way it is supposed to be read or operate.

Comment: Hi Nadim, this URL is showing that a 'pageview' is taking place, you're looking for an 'event' (t=event).  The actual reason is a missing call to your anonymous function inside the ready() call.  you defin your function that you want to make happen on DOM ready but you don't execute the code. And you need to use jQuery instead of $ because that is how your site is written Try this:  jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('.fancybox-nav').on('click', function(){ ga('send', 'event', 'lightbox', 'lightboxClicks', 'lightboxPhotos', 100); }); }());

Comment: Thanks again, dmpg_tom. Actually that was an older code. The page is coded with the correct "jQuery" naming instead of "$" and it still produces the result I showed earlier.

Comment: you're nearly there, just compare the code that I pasted in my previous comment to the code in your placeholder.js file.  All you need is to add the trailing () at the end and you'll have tracking that works.  the reason you need this is to actually call your anonymous function you've setup there.

Comment: Hi dmpg_tom, I fixed the code on the website now. I am still uncertain if it is working or not. Btw, wanna thank you for all your help thus far. Here is the site URL again: http://cultmontreal.com/photos/151020-justintrudeau-cl/

Comment: nadim, just realised i made a bit of an oversight.  Because the overlays are created dynamically we actually have to delegate a click event to every .fancy-nav link in the body (previous solution just looked for existing elements).  I've updated the solution code appropriately.  Just replace what you have in your placeholder.js with that.  Also note the extra paragraph re debugging.

Comment: Okay, thanks dmpgtom. So finally, here is the code I am using: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('body').on('click', '.fancybox-nav', function(){ 
  ga('send', 'event', 'lightbox', 'lightboxClicks', 'lightboxPhotos', 100);
});
}()); I'll check it now on Chrome to see if it's working.

Comment: @dmpgtom, it seems to be functioning, can you check on your end only if you have a moment. I get a little popup everytime I click on the arrow in the lightbox, I get a message that states "javascript:;" Thanks again, appreciate it.